# Exclude Rails ActiveRecord from query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm developing an marketplace app where sellers can list items to sell. On the listing show page, I developed a widget called "other items from this seller". I use the below query to pull these items into the view.

```
Listing.where(:user_id => @listing.user)
```

This works but it includes the activerecord. Since this is a widget for "other items" I want to exclude the listing whose page the user is currently on. Note that the "user_id" field in the listing model is the sellers user id.

How would I modify this? I tried the below but it gives me an error saying it expects an "=>".

```
Listing.where(:user_id => @listing.user, :id != @listing.id)
```

Comment: The `where` you've defined there is an implicit hash, so you can't throw in arbitrary code in the middle of it, that violates the syntax rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply using array parameter to `where`:

```
@listing.user.listings.where(["id != ?", @listing])
```

OR (**better performance**)

```
Listing.where(["user_id = ? AND id != ?", @listing.user_id, @listing.id])
```

Comment: Missing an `AND` in your second example.

Comment: Additionally the `[ ... ]` brackets are not necessary, at least not in modern versions of Rails. Just cleans this up a little.

Comment: thanks guys! I used the second example above but is one of the methods preferred over the other in terms of performance?

Comment: I added a created_at condition to it so I get recent items but I get an wrong number of arguments error(3 for 2). `Listing.where("category = ? AND id != ? AND created_at >=", @listing.category, @listing.id, 10.days.ago)`

Comment: You are missing `?`.... `Listing.where("category = ? AND id != ? AND created_at >= ?", @listing.category, @listing.id, 10.days.ago)`

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, if you are using rails 4.x you could use .where.not

`Listing.where(user_id: @listing.user_id).where.not(id: @listing.id)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [RAJ's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25532791/1047207) answer, you can chain the two clauses to make one query

```
Listing.where(:user_id => @listing.user).where("id != ?", @listing.id)
```

Comment: `Listing.where(:user_id => @listing.user)` this will cause error `@listing.user` it should be `@listing.user_id`